# Mapping permissions to information

Tags: facebook, permissions

Is there a way to access the fields that each permission is mapped to from Facebook in a programmatic way?

Say I have a list of User connections which I want to cache (i.e. links, notes, feed, and games). I also want to get real-time updates to let me know if the read_stream permissions have changed, and invalidate the cache if app doesn't have read_stream permissions anymore. I could build a map, based on the documentation, that would tell me that read_stream affects links, notes, and feed. If in the future the facebook documenation changes to also include games in the read_stream feed, my application would be caching data for games without authorization if the read_stream was not valid, and I would have to modify that map to account for this.

Is there a way to, on the fly, obtain the maps that relate each permission to each field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this programmatically.  For the most part, it's fairly well documented on their site.  Maybe you could make a database version of this.  Just be aware, Facebook is quick to change things and maintaining will become a chore.  Happy Coding!